# Spring boot mockito mock method according to input parameters

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, arguments

I have an special case that I have no idea about how to solve.

I am testing a service class method with spring boot, junit and mockito. In the class method I am testing, it call an internal method also, something like this:

```java
@Service
public class ServiceFacadeImpl implements ServiceFacade {

  //Some autowire and stuffs

  @Override
  public List<Log> getObjectLog(String objectCode) {
    List<Log> objectLogs = objectRepository.findByObjectCode(objectCode);
    return objectLogs;
  }

  @Override
  public MyObjectWrapper getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode(String externalCode) {
    List<String> objectCodes = objectRepository.findobjectCodesByExternalCode(externalCode);

    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(objectCodes)){
      return null;
    }

    MyObjectWrapper wrapper = new MyObjectWrapper();
    wrapper.setExternalCode(externalCode);
    wrapper.setObjectLogs(new ArrayList<>());
 
    for (String objectCode : objectCodes ) {
      ObjectLogWrapper logWrapper = new ObjectLogWrapper();
      List<Log> logs = getObjectLog(opCode);   // Call to internal method of the class
      logWrapper.setObjectCode(objectCode);
      logWrapper.setObjectLog(logs);
      wrapper.getObjectLogs().add(logWrapper);
    }
    return MyObjectWrapper ;
  }
}
```

I am trying to mock in my test this getObjectLog(opCode) when testing the "getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode" method to return different Log list according to the parameter received

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class ObjectServiceFacadeImplTest {

  //Some mock beans

  @Autowired private ServiceFacade serviceFacade;

@Test
  @DisplayName("test")
  void testGetMyObjectsLogByExternalCode() {

    // Given
    List<String> mockObCodes = Arrays.asList( "obcode1","obcode2" );
    when(repository.findObjectCodesByexternalCode(any())).thenReturn(mockObCodes );

    List<OperationLogDTO> mockLogsOb1 = Arrays.asList( new Log(), new Log() );  //Size 2 for ob1
    when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog(eq( "obcode1"))).thenReturn( mockLogsOb1 );

    List<OperationLogDTO> mockLogsOb2 = Collections.singletonList( new Log() ); //Size 1 for ob1
    when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog(eq( "obcode2"))).thenReturn( mockLogsOb2 );

    // When
    MyObjectWrapper objectWrapper = serviceFacade.getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode("TESTCODE");

    // Then
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getExternalCode(),"TESTCODE" );
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getObjects().size(),2 );
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getObjects().get( 0 ).getLogs().size(),2 );  //Fails because it gets the second mock return value
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getObjects().get( 0 ).getCode(),"obcode1" ); //Fails because it gets the second mock return value
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getObjects().get( 1 ).getLogs().size(),1 );
    assertEquals( objectWrapper.getObjects().get( 1 ).getCode(),"obcode2" );
  }
```

The code has been changed because of confidential stuff, but the logic of what I am trying to do I think is clear

The logic basically is that I have the main object that contains secondary objects and this secondary object contains logs objects also. There is a method that gets the logs of each secondary object and another method that gives a primary object code it obtains all logs of all secondary objects associated in a wrapper object with all info.

The problem here is that when the getObjectLogs is called as a mock is always returning the second case indecently of the parameter received. I always get a log lost of size one when calling it.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE:

I lso have try to use a @SpyBean instead of an @Autowired for the service but again it always return the same

```
@SpyBean private ServiceFacade serviceFacade;
```

Comment: You have `serviceFacade` and `operationServiceFacade` in your test, which one is correct? Additionally, since you are auto wiring `serviceFacade`, you will not be able to mock anything regarding it.

Comment: @JoãoDias I have eddited the fail.

Comment: @JoãoDias I know that I am Autowiring it but I need to mock also an additional method, so how can I do it? also it seems it is mocking it but always returning the obcode2 response

Comment: You could try to use a Spy, but it does sound better that you mock whatever is inside the `getObjectLog` method. Since you didn't provide it's code, we still can't help you with it.

Comment: Can you please include the complete code for `getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode` and `getObjectLog`? Thanks.

Comment: I have added some aditional code... the point @EduardoBueno is that I already have a test for the method getObjectLog(), so moking the calls to the internal methods of it, it will be like repeating code and creating a dependency between to test method

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido, can you please add both `ObjectLogWrapper` and `ObjectLogWrapper` complete code? Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido, please include both `ObjectLogWrapper` and `ObjectLogWrapper`. They are indeed relevant because you are dealing with Collections and not all Collections keep the order of insertion. Additionally, I see `wrapper.getObjectLogs().add(logWrapper);` calls and then in the test I see `objectWrapper.getObjects().get( 1 ).getCode()`. What is the difference between `getObjectLogs()` and `getObjects()`? This is why it is important to include both classes.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - try to mock only collaborators, not your object under test.

Having said that - a Spy can be used to mock parts of object under test.

I don't really see the need to use `@SpringBootTest` for your service, so here goes plain Mockito version:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ObjectServiceFacadeImplTest {

    @Mock
    ObjectRepository repository;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceFacadeImpl serviceFacade;

    @Test
    void testGetMyObjectsLogByExternalCode() {

        // Given
        List<String> mockObCodes = List.of("obcode1", "obcode2");
        String externalCode = "TESTCODE";
        when(repository.findObjectCodesByExternalCode(externalCode)).thenReturn(mockObCodes);

        List<Log> mockLogsOb1 = List.of(new Log(), new Log());  //Size 2 for ob1
        when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog("obcode1")).thenReturn(mockLogsOb1);

        List<Log> mockLogsOb2 = List.of(new Log()); //Size 1 for ob1
        when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog("obcode2")).thenReturn(mockLogsOb2);

        // When
        MyObjectWrapper objectWrapper = serviceFacade.getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode(externalCode);

        // Then
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getExternalCode(), externalCode);
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getObjects().size(), 2);
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getObjects().get(0).getLogs().size(), 2);  //Fails because it gets the second mock return value
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getObjects().get(0).getCode(), "obcode1"); //Fails because it gets the second mock return value
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getObjects().get(1).getLogs().size(), 1);
        assertEquals(objectWrapper.getObjects().get(1).getCode(), "obcode2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing with mocks you should make clear wich class is under test and which other classes are just dependencies that should be mocked. In your case you want to test `ServiceFacade` on method `getMyObjectsLogByExternalCode()`.

**So please keep the whole ServiceFacade object as autowired Spring bean, don't use spys or try to mock parts of it.**

Please also note, that you cannot mock methods of autowired services, nor you can trick it with a spy. A spy is actually a facade that can only redirect the initial method call. Internal method calls always refer to the real object.

But as you already did, it makes sense to mock the objectRepository, as it should be ouside of your unit test scope. In your code I can see two methods of this object called:

```java
  objectRepository.findobjectCodesByExternalCode(externalCode); // called once to get the list
  objectRepository.findByObjectCode(objectCode); // called twice, which each element of the list
```

You should both mock them with standard Mockito style:

```java
  List<String> mockObCodes = Arrays.asList("obcode1", "obcode2");
  when(objectRepository.findObjectCodesByexternalCode(any())).thenReturn(mockObCodes );

  List<OperationLogDTO> mockLogsOb1 = Arrays.asList( new Log(), new Log() );  //Size 2 for ob1
  when(objectRepository.findByObjectCode("obcode1")).thenReturn( mockLogsOb1 );

  List<OperationLogDTO> mockLogsOb2 = Collections.singletonList( new Log() ); //Size 1 for ob1
  when(objectRepository.findByObjectCode("obcode2")).thenReturn( mockLogsOb2 );
```

I hope this will make your test run, please let me know,

Comment: But imagine the case I have a class with a private method that is called internally a lot of times in other methods of the class actually I am testing the same part of code and calling it all this times, or even better a method that seems to be short but it is divived in 15 private method to make a better understanding of it. If I am not able to test the private methods independent and the main one with mocks of the privates, this cases are a mess to test because actually a method divided in 15 smaller method and easier to test, must be tested as a huge one that makes that really hard to test

Comment: Same applies with a public method that is called a lot of times interally as in my case

Comment: When unit testing, you should consider the class under test as a black box. Imagine someone else has written it. It should not matter in how many private methods the code is split up and what is called internally. For you in the role as a tester, the unit should just work and do it's job.

If you have the feeling, that private methods should be tested, this is a strong indicator that your class has become to complictated. Maybe the private method should be refactored into a new service? Have you considered separation of concerns? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: yes but I am the tester, not the developer :(

Comment: Then I can only say: concentrate on the public methods and talk to your developers about design for testability. ;-)

Comment: oK thanks. I know that it is possible to do that with PowerMockito but it does not support Junit 5, just Junit 4 :(

Answer (score 1):

Here `getObjectLogs` always returns second value. The issue here is when you mock for the first time `Mockito` stores `mockLogsOb1` as a response. When you mock for the second time rather than adding it as response, it replaces the value to `mockLogsOb2`. 
As Mockito works by creating proxies for the objects. You can handle the above scenario in many ways.

1. By chaining the responses

```
when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog(anyString()).thenReturn(mockLogsOb1).thenReturn(mockLogsOb2 );
```

2. Returning response in classic style (Check for mockito version support)

```
 when(serviceFacade.getObjectLog(anyString()).thenReturn(mockLogsOb1, mockLogsOb2);
```

3. Returning response using `Answer` to give multiple response

```
when(mock.someMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(
     new Answer() {
         public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
             Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
             Object mock = invocation.getMock();
             return "called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args);
         }
 });

 //Following prints "called with arguments: [foo]"
 System.out.println(mock.someMethod("foo"));
```

You can check the arguments passed and return response accordingly.

Comment: How I can get testValue1? thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your query. We can get the arguments passed from the invocation object. That value of object can be used in test condition  and response object from the answer can be returned accordingly. But I always prefer the 1st way of approach by chaining the responses.